# How to get document.cookie to work properly?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have been trying to set a simple cookie to the current page but it does not seem to work(It does not show I have a cookie saved and any alert made with document.cookie shows up without text.

```
Cookies = {};

Cookies.cookiefile = blue;
Cookies.cookiekey = 5;

function Cookies.save(){
document.cookie= Cookies.cookiefile+"="+Cookies.cookiekey+";max-age="+60*60*24*10+";path=/";
alert(document.cookie);
}
```

Comment: So what are you doing, are we supposed to guess what your code looks like ?

Comment: `function Cookies.save(){` isn't proper syntax.  It should be `Cookies.save = function(){`.

Comment: Read the error console for SyntaxErrors. There is no reason to answer this question in any more detail because the fundamental usage is "not using it". (Also, uhm, try a cookie tutorial, the assignment to the property also shows a general lack-of-following-existing-code.)

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've shown your actual code, it appears you have a script error that is keeping your code from running.  This piece of code:

```
function Cookies.save(){...}
```

is not proper syntax for declaring a function.  You should check your browser error console or debug console for script errors and it would probably show you that.  You can use the format:

```
Cookies.save = function() {...}
```

---

This part of the answer provided before the OP offered any code.

Here's a set of utility functions for handling cookies.  Without seeing your code, we can't really know what you're not doing right, but if you use these functions and try to access the cookie from an allowable page, it should work.

```
// createCookie()
// name and value are strings
// days is the number of days until cookie expiration
// path is optional and should start with a leading "/" 
//   and can limit which pages on your site can 
//   read the cookie.
//   By default, all pages on the site can read
//   the cookie if path is not specified
function createCookie(name, value, days, path) {
    var date, expires = "";
    path = path || "/";
    if (days) {
        date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=" + path;
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```